# Converting data to a CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm bringing in data that is json.dumps'd to go through the MQTT broker. After I do a json.loads, I'm getting this data in return.

```
[['date here', '1713180'], ['date here', '1713181'], ['date here', '1713182'], ['date here', '1713183'], ['date here', '1713184']]
```

I've tried numerous other threads on csv writing, but I'm completely lost as to how to get this written properly to a CSV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving zip list to csv in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265133/saving-zip-list-to-csv-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([['date here', '1713180'], ['date here', '1713181'], ['date here', '1713182'], ['date here', '1713183'], ['date here', '1713184']])
df.columns=['timestamp','data']
df.to_csv('test.csv',columns=['timestamp','data'],index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

"You can use pandas:

if you don't have pandas installed run the following in order to install it:

```
pip install pandas
```

then, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['date here', '1713180'], ['date here', '1713181'], ['date here', '1713182'], ['date here', '1713183'], ['date here', '1713184']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```